# Observing django-background-tasks metrics with Prometheus

Tags: python, django, prometheus

I am trying to collect application-specific Prometheus metrics in Django for functions that are called by django-background-tasks.

In my application `models.py` file, I am first adding a custom metric with:

```
my_task_metric = Summary("my_task_metric ", "My task metric")
```

Then, I am adding this to my function to capture the timestamp at which this function was last run successfully:

```
@background()
def my_function():

    # my function code here

    # collecting the metric
    my_task_metric.observe((datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc) - datetime(1970, 1, 1).replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)).total_seconds())
```

When I bring up Django, the metric is created and accessible in `/metrics`. However, after this function is run, the value for sum is 0 as if the metric is not observed. Am I missing something?

Or is there a better way to monitor django-background-tasks with Prometheus? I have tried using the model of django-background-tasks but I found it a bit cumbersome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a decorator leveraging the Prometheus Pushgateway feature

```
def push_metric_to_prometheus(function):

    registry = CollectorRegistry()

    Gauge(f'{function.__name__}_last_successful_run', f'Last time {function.__name__} successfully finished',
          registry=registry).set_to_current_time()

    push_to_gateway('bolero.club:9091', job='batchA', registry=registry)

    return function
```

and then on my function (the order of the decorators is important)

```
@background()
@push_metric_to_prometheus
def my_function():

    # my function code here
```